# php pagination, something wrong

Tags: php, html, pagination, filesystems

Some code from me.

```
$files = glob("pardod/*.html");
$record_count  = 5;
$total_pages   = ceil(count($files)/$record_count);
$page          = $_GET['page'];
$offset        = ($page-1)*$record_count;
$files_filter  = array_slice($files, $offset,$record_count);

for ($i = 0; $i<$filecount; $i++){
    if ($page){
        $start = ($page - 1) * $record_count;
    }else{
        $start = 0;
    }
}

if($total_pages > 1){
   if($page != 1){
      echo '<a href="pardod.php?page='.($page-1).'">Atpakal</a>';
   }
   if($page != $total_pages){
      echo '<a href="pardod.php?page='.($page+1).'">Uz priekšu</a>';
   }
}
```

The php pagination dont work, i am just learning how to make, where is a problem?

The `*.html files` didn't shows :(

Comment: Do you get some kind of error? How doo you know that is not working? What did you expect?

Comment: html files didnt shows, he make pages, but it gives nothing becouse the html files didnt show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for pagination

```
  <?php

  $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

  $page=$_REQUEST['page'];

  if ($page < 1)
  {
  $page = 1;
  }
  $resultsPerPage =15;
  $startResults = ($page - 1) * $resultsPerPage;
  $numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tablename'));
  $totalPages = ceil($numberOfRows / $resultsPerPage);
  echo"<center><table border='1' bordercolor='blue' height='90%' width='90%'> <tr><th     bgcolor='silver'>Name</th><th bgcolor='silver'>Password</th><th      bgcolor='silver'>Question</th><th bgcolor='silver'> Answer</th><th        bgcolor='silver'>Image</th> </tr>";

$i=1;
                                                                                  $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM password LIMIT   $startResults,        $resultsPerPage");

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
       {

   }

   echo"</tr></table></center>";

      echo '<center><a href="?page=1">First</a>&nbsp';

  if($page > 1)
  echo '<a href="?page='.($page - 1).'">Back</a>&nbsp';

  for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i++)
      {
if($i == $page)
  echo '<strong>'.$i.'</strong>&nbsp';
 else
   echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>&nbsp';
     }

  if ($page < $totalPages)
  echo '<a href="?page='.($page + 1).'">Next</a>&nbsp;';

   echo '<a href="?page='.$totalPages.'">Last</a></center>';
 ?>
```

Comment: But i dont have database :/, this homepage is on filesystem.

Comment: when you use SELECT * FROM tablename for totalrows, what is the meaning of pagination. because if we are getting total records from db and plus current page record filter, It does two db query request.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
$limit = ( isset($_GET['limit'])) ? $_GET['limit'] : 5;
if (strtolower($limit) == 'all') {
    $limit = 'all';
} else {
    $limit = filter_var($limit, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if (trim($limit) == '') {
        $limit = 5;
    }
}

$page = ( isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$page = filter_var($page, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$links = ( isset($_GET['links'])) ? $_GET['links'] : 1;
$links = filter_var($links, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

**Here is the link where step by step described all the process in details.**

[Simple Pagination in PHP By Learning Ocean Team](https://www.learningoceanteam.com/pagination-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap, you can use the following

```
function pagination($page, $count) {
        global $options;
        $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";
        $actual_link = trim(str_replace("page=".$page, "", $actual_link), "&");

        $lenght = ceil($count/$options->get("result_per_page"));
        if ($page <= 3) {
            if ($lenght < 5) {
                $first = 0;
                $last = $lenght-1;
            } else {
                $first = 0;
                $last = 4;
            }
        } else if ($page < ($lenght-2)) {
            $first = $page-2;
            $last = $page+2;
        } else if ($page <= $lenght) {
            $first = $page-5;
            $last = $lenght-1;
        }
        if ($page > 0) {
            $prev = $page-1;
            $next = $page+1;
        } else {
            $prev = 0;
            $next = $page+1;
        }

        echo '<span>Viewing page '.($page+1).' of '.$lenght.'</span><br>';
        echo '<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">';
        echo '<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">';
        if ($prev > 0) {
            echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$actual_link.'&page=0">&laquo;&laquo;</a></li>';
            echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$actual_link.'&page='.$prev.'">&laquo;</a></li>';
        }
        for ($i = $first; $i<=$last; $i++) {
            if ($i == $page) {
                $active = ' active';
            } else {
                $active = '';
            }
            echo '<li class="page-item'.$active.'"><a class="page-link" href="'.$actual_link.'&page='.$i.'">'.($i+1).'</a></li>';
        }
        if ($next < $last) {
            echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$actual_link.'&page='.$next.'">&raquo;</a></li>';
            echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="'.$actual_link.'&page='.($lenght-1).'">&raquo;&raquo;</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</nav>';
    }
```

to call the function

```
$pageNumber = 1;
$totalRowCount = 5000;
pagination($pageNumber, $totalRowCount);
```